# Rails namespaced models autoloading issue?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, namespaces, autoload

Here's the setup:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :project_subject_areas, class_name: "Project::SubjectArea"
  has_many :subject_areas, through: :project_subject_areas
end

class SubjectArea < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :project_subject_areas, class_name: "Project::SubjectArea"
  has_many :projects, through: :project_subject_areas
end

class Project::SubjectArea < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :subject_area, class_name: '::SubjectArea'
end
```

Running this in Rails:

```
[ SubjectArea.to_s, Project::SubjectArea.to_s ].inspect
```

gives:

```
["SubjectArea", "SubjectArea"]
```

but running this (after server restart):

```
[ Project::SubjectArea.to_s, SubjectArea.to_s ].inspect
```

gives:

```
["Project::SubjectArea", "SubjectArea"]
```

file structure is:

```
models/project.rb
models/subject_area.rb
models/project/subject_area.rb
```

I can bypass this with `require project/subject_area` manually, but am I doing something wrong with this namespacing?

Is there any other way to namespace my models?

When Rails generates namespaces `rails generate Project::X` I get Project as a module, but I need it to be an ActiveRecord class. I also have some other models that belong to Project and I really want them to be namespaced and in models/project/ directory.